# Do transaction fees scale with the size of the transaction?

Tags: transactions, fees

Does the transaction fee increase with larger transfers of XLM?

If so, by how much?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Transaction fees are calculated over the number of operations into a transaction

Each operation "costs" a base fee (currently* 100 stroops -> 0.00001 XLM) regardless of operation type or operation content

So if you have a transaction with only one payment operation, you will always* pay 0.00001 XLM. This apply both if you send 100XLM or 1B XLM

More info [here](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/concepts/fees.html#transaction-fee)

*Base fee amount could be changed in the future